# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type from String: not one of the values accepted for Enum class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm upgrading a Spring Boot web service from Kotlin `1.4.32` to `1.5.0`.

```kotlin
// Before:
kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.32"
kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.32"

// After:
kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.0"
kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.0"
```

After upgrading and running the API, I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `models.SeasonType` from String "Season": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [NO_SEASON, UNKNOWN, SEASON]
```

`SeasonType` is an enum class:

```kotlin
package models

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator

enum class SeasonType(val value: String) {

    SEASON("Season"),
    NO_SEASON("NoSeason"),
    UNKNOWN("Unknown");

    companion object {
        @JsonCreator
        @JvmStatic
        private fun creator(serializedValue: String): SeasonType =
            values().firstOrNull { it.value == serializedValue } ?: UNKNOWN
    }

}
```

Why does deserialization fail after upgrading Kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by upgrading to Kotlin `1.6.x`.